# How to permanently mount password-protected samba share with workgroup

Tags: mount, samba, fstab

I can use the following command to log into a samba share on my network:

```
smbclient -L //host.name.com -U myUser --workgroup=WORK
```

where `myUser` is my username and `WORK` is the name of the workgroup. I can also access this share via Places->Connect to Network without issues.

However, I can't mount the drive permanently. Here's what I did after following the [Ubuntu instructions on mounting a sambda share permanently](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountWindowsSharesPermanently):

I have created a file called `~/.smbcredentials` and run `chmod 600 ~/.smbcredentials`:

```
user=WORK/myUser
password=pass
```

(where `pass` is my password)

I have also added the following line to my `/etc/fstab`:

```
//host.name.com/ /media/share cifs credentials=/home/myUser/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm 0 0
```

I have also run `sudo mkdir /media/share`.

However, when I run `sudo mount -a` I see the following:

```
mount error(13): Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are permission of /media/share directory. Try chmod 777 just to troubleshoot

Comment: I ran `sudo chmod 777 /media/share`, same result.

Comment: I tried `chmod 777 ~/.smbcredentials` as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change your `~/.smbcredentials`

```
user=myUser
password=pass
domain=WORK
```

That's all **;)**

The problem occurs when you use the user name and the domain name together.

---

And please revert the changes for `~/.smbcredentials`

```
chmod o-rwx,-x ~/.smbcredentials
```

Comment: Nice one. Could you explain how you found this information?

Comment: I have used my working configuration and changed according to your specifications. Since I was sure my configuration works, the following was simple.

Comment: Ok good enough for me :) I'll award the bounty once I'm allowed.